# SQL Statement Assistance is needed

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 2 tables, 1 is called SourceProperties. and the other is called Properties.

a source can have many properties.

SourceProperties contains the following attributes or columns(SourceID,PropertyID,Value).
    Properties contains the following attributes or columns(PropertyID,PropertyType,PropertyName).

for instance,

```
Select * from SourceProperties where SourceID=1
```

will return the following

```
1     33     www.google.com/,...m,sand
1     34     true
1     35     Journal
1     77     false
```

additionally,

```
Select * from Properties where PropertyID=34
```

will return:

```
34 bit IpAuthenticated

Select * from Properties where PropertyID=77
```

will return:

```
77 bit ContainsBooks
```

my question is this, if i need to select all the property values for a certain SourceID
so i can get such a result

1     wwww.google.com   true  Journal  false

what can i do?
thx in advanced!

Answer (score 5):

I think this might be what you are looking for

```
SELECT SourceID, GROUP_CONCAT(Value SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM SourceProperties
WHERE SourceID = 1
GROUP BY SourceID
```

This will give you all the properties, separated by spaces (but not as individual columns).  If you wanted each property as an individual column, that would involve some pretty fancy dynamic SQL and would be considerably more difficult.